# Unable to open https webpages

Tags: networking, https

i am new here so please forgive me if i didnt put this question "by the rules".

So, the problem: few months ago I wanted to switch from Win to Ubuntu 14.04 on my netbook (that i dont use that much), installation went regularly fine but from the beginning i have this problem that pages where is needed to log in start loading but nothing happens. so, pages like Facebook, Yahoo mail, Chrome Google account, my bank account and so on. For example, Facebook front page is opened normally, i can type in my login data, press enter, my homepage opens and after nothing. Any other pages (on my Facebook account) afterwards starts loading but it doesnt open at all! And it is the same situation with all other previously mentioned https webistes.

Troubleshooting (to help specify the problem): 
-I tried on the same netbook to install Ubuntu 12.04, the same problems occur.
-My wife's netbook has Windows, works without problem.
-In the meantime i bought a new laptop, tried to install Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 and also there happens the same.
- Our "family" desktop computer has Ubuntu 12.04, which was installed last year and doesnt have similar issues (and is up-to-date)
- I usually use Google Chrome, but to test I also tried Firefox and few other browsers, the same problem on all browsers.
- "Normal" http pages open without any problem

There are few other similar questions being asked here already, where solution like decreasing MTU, updateing Ubuntu, turning off IPv6, setting up free DNS domain and so on were suggested. I tried some of these and in the meantime got lost from all of these options, so i hoped that you can help me and guide me, to start again and to finally find a solution for this.

Its a bit longer message, but i thought it can be useful if i write as many details as possible.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, :) late ha?. Is your clock correct or sync to an online time server?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to investigate what's going on behind...

**By capturing network communication**

Install `wireshark` and try to capture the communication, then set filter to https and you may see, which packets are being sent to the server, what's being received then, etc.

NOTE: If you close all the other programs which generate network traffic, your results will be easier to read.

*WHAT YOU COULD DISCOVER BY THAT?*

--> Whether the communication exists or not. It may be i.e. blocked by some firewall or whatever. You should see that it's communicating with the server in a normal way.

**Try to attach `strace` to see, what's the browser process doing:**

1. Prepare the page with your login and password
2. Check the PID of Firefox: `ps aux | grep firefox`
3. Attach `strace` to it: `strace -tt -p <PID> -f -o strace.log`
4. Then try to login and wait for a while
5. Detach `strace` by pressing `Ctrl-C`

You should see what's happening there. All the syscalls in the log have a timestamp (`-tt` option), so if you wait before and after the login and watch the system time, you should be able to determine which syscalls are related to it.

Everything should be done by one particular thread (so you could look on subsets of the syscalls which have the same thread ID).

*WHAT YOU COULD DISCOVER BY THAT?*

--> What's happening at the IO level of the browser process. You should focus on `recv`, `recvfrom`, `recvmsg`, `socket`, `send`, `sendto`, `sendmsg` syscalls (they are used for socket communication). You should check whether they are successful (the return values are not negative or like ESOME_ERROR), etc.

I would check whether other encrypted communication works (like ssh, etc.), I would check whether some proxy settings could be the culprit. I hope it could help you to get closer.